# Loop to extract html from given URLs

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract html information from a group of URLs that have been archived on a particular website.
I need to loop this to extract from all URLs in a list

```
#Finding the specific p class that contains daily information
dailydata = (soup.find('p', attrs={"class": "style22"}).get_text())
dailydata
#Getting rid of the \n's and \t's in the string
to_replace =['\n\t\t\t\t\t\t','\n\t\t\t\t\t\t ','\xa0','  ',' ']
for rep1 in to_replace:
    dailydata = dailydata.replace(rep1, '_')


rep2 = ['__','_']
for r in rep2:
    dailydata = dailydata.replace(r, '_')

#Splitting the string into lists
splitdd = dailydata.split('_')


#Finding the specific division class that contains the report information
reportinfo = (soup.find('div', attrs={"class": "style18"}).get_text())
#Getting rid of \n
reportinfo.replace('\n',' ')
reportinfo = reportinfo.split(' ')

#Finding the specific p class that contains title information for daily data
titles = list(soup.find('p', attrs={"class": "style21"}).get_text())
titles = titles.replace('\n\t\t\t\t\t\t', ' ')

#Constructing necessary data tables
data1 = {'Date':[reportinfo[3]],
     'Water Temp (Little River)':[splitdd[0] +' degrees Fahrenheit'],
     'Stream Flow Rate':[splitdd[2] + ' Feet ' + splitdd[4] + ' CF/s'],
     'Sunrise':[splitdd[6]],
     'Sunset':[splitdd[7]],
     'Rainfall 2023 YTD Knoxville Apt':[splitdd[8]],
     'Rainfall Normal YTD Knoxville Apt':[splitdd[9]]
}

data_column_index = ['Date',
     'Water Temp (Little River)',
     'Stream Flow Rate',
     'Sunrise',
     'Sunset',
     'Rainfall 2023 YTD Knoxville Apt',
     'Rainfall Normal YTD Knoxville Apt'
]

dates = [reportinfo[3]]

reoccuring_data = [[reportinfo[3]],
     [splitdd[0] +' degrees Fahrenheit'],
     [splitdd[2] + ' Feet ' + splitdd[4] + ' CF/s'],
     [splitdd[6]],
     [splitdd[7]],
     [splitdd[8]],
     [splitdd[9]]
]

#Calling data to put into dataframe
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = data1, index = dates, columns = data_column_index)
reoccurdf = pd.DataFrame(data = reoccuring_data)
reoccurdf

df1 = pd.concat([df1, df1], ignore_index = True)

#Saving to csv file
df1.to_csv(save_path + 'output.csv', mode='a', index=False, header = False)
```

Here is my 'archive' scrape program. I can't figure out how to loop the HTML scrape for a single day (code above) to extract information from all URLs in a list.
Below is my "archive scraping program" I have the URLs I need to scrape in a list.

```
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from datetime import date, timedelta
import requests
import pprint
import re
import pyperclip


#We need from 2017.11.1 to 2023.10.26
#The format for this particular html is 'mmddyy'
def daterange(start_date, end_date):
    for n in range(int((end_date - start_date).days)):
        yield start_date + timedelta(n)

start_date = date(2017,11,1)
end_date = date(2023,10,30)

archive_date_range_list = []
for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
    x = (single_date.strftime("%m%d%y"))
    archive_date_range_list.append(x)

new_list_dates = ','.join([x for x in archive_date_range_list])
new_list_dates = new_list_dates.split(",")

#Little River Outfitters website URL with the archive date variable
#we need the format URL1+"date"+URL2
URL1 = [r'https://littleriveroutfitters.com/WEBSITE-2008/pages/fishing/']
URL2 = [r'.htm']

#loop to configure the particular website
website_dates_list = []
for i in new_list_dates:
    x1 = URL1,i,URL2
    website_dates_list.append(x1)

#making the list of url that need to be scraped
pages = new_list_dates
baseurl = 'https://littleriveroutfitters.com/WEBSITE-2008/pages/fishing/'

my_url_list= [''.join(map(str, [baseurl, p, '.htm'])) for p in pages]

#Now I need to get data from URLs from my_url_lists
```

I have tried to run a beautiful_soup loop with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do give you an idea how you could go - Use a while loop and add a day in each iteration, if you reach `end_date` simply `break` the loop.

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date, timedelta
import requests

start_date = date(2017,11,1)
end_date = date(2017,11,20)

data = []
while True:
    start_date.strftime("%m%d%y")

    url = f'https://littleriveroutfitters.com/WEBSITE-2008/pages/fishing/{start_date.strftime("%m%d%y")}.htm'
    
    try:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text)

        d = soup.select('table table tr:has(img[alt*="Fishing Gauge"]) td:has(p :not(img))')
        d = dict(zip(d[0].stripped_strings, d[1].stripped_strings))
        d.update({'date': start_date})
        data.append(d)
    except:
        print(start_date, url)

    if start_date == end_date:
        break
    else:
        start_date = start_date + timedelta(days=1)


pd.DataFrame(data)
```

###### Output

|  | Water Temperature Little River | Stream Flow | Sunrise | Sunset | Rainfall 2017 YTD Knoxville Apt | Rainfall Normal YTD Knoxville Apt | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 47.7 Fahrenheit | 2.16 Feet 239 CFS | 7:58 | 6:40 | 45.31" | 39.95" | 2017-11-01 |
| 1 | 51.8 Fahrenheit | 2.11 Feet 222 CFS | 7:59 | 6:39 | 45.31" | 39.46" | 2017-11-02 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 18 | 51.1 Fahrenheit | 2.17 Feet 242 CFS | 7:16 | 5:26 | 48.47" | 41.56" | 2017-11-19 |
| 19 | 44.2 Fahrenheit | 1.90 Feet 159 CFS | 7:17 | 5:26 | 48.47" | 41.70" | 2017-11-20 |

Comment: While that does work. It only works for the date range 2017,11,1 to 2018,8,2.

Comment: After, 2018-08-02, no results are given for the dataframe. Does the issue lie in the soup.select line?

Comment: As mentioned, it's just meant to be an idea generator, there's no claim to a bulletproof application, especially since websites and structures can change over a long period of time. that's where using your own domain knowledge on the project would come in handy with the code. simply look at your results and adjust the selector - And yes you are close to - Hint `soup.select('table table tr:has(img[alt*="Fishing Gauge"]) td:has(p :not(img))')`