# I am trying to extract a table from an html and I am getting hung up on my html parser

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date, timedelta
import requests
import os

start_date = date(2018,8,2)
end_date = date(2018,8,8)

data = []
while True:
    start_date.strftime("%m%d%y")

    url = f'https://littleriveroutfitters.com/WEBSITE-2008/pages/fishing/{start_date.strftime("%m%d%y")}.htm'
    
    try:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text)

        d = soup.select('table table tr:has(img[alt*="Fishing Gauge"]) td:has(p)')
        d = dict(zip(d[0].stripped_strings, d[1].stripped_strings))
        d.update({'date': start_date})
        data.append(d)
    except:
        print(start_date, url)

    if start_date == end_date:
        break
    else:
        start_date = start_date + timedelta(days=1)


df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

save_path = "C:/Users/Bay/Documents/Python_Files/fish_info_scrape/"

#df_1.to_csv(save_path + 'report_output.csv', mode = 'w')

df_1
```

The above code works for August 2nd, 2018, but any date after, the code will not work.
I am trying to fix the line
       `d = soup.select('table table tr:has(img[alt*="Fishing Gauge"]) td:has(p)')`
but getting no luck.
Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried
       `d = soup.select('blockquote p:has(img[alt*="Fishing Gauge"])')`
with no luck.
I was expecting to receive an output with the August 3rd - August 8th dates completed like August 2nd.

```
  Water Temperature Little River        Stream Flow Sunrise Sunset Rainfall 2018 YTD Knoxville Apt Rainfall Normal YTD Knoxville Apt        date       
0                64.4 Fahrenheit  2.93 Feet 678 CFS    6:44   8:39                          33.62"                            30.45"  2018-08-02       
1                            NaN                NaN     NaN    NaN                             NaN                               NaN  2018-08-03       
2                            NaN                NaN     NaN    NaN                             NaN                               NaN  2018-08-04       
3                            NaN                NaN     NaN    NaN                             NaN                               NaN  2018-08-05       
4                            NaN                NaN     NaN    NaN                             NaN                               NaN  2018-08-06       
5                            NaN                NaN     NaN    NaN                             NaN                               NaN  2018-08-07       
6                            NaN                NaN     NaN    NaN                             NaN                               NaN  2018-08-08
```

Comment: Have you tried using pd.read_html?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loop to extract html from given URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77391376/loop-to-extract-html-from-given-urls)  Please read the replies to your comments carefully and keep track of any changes. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The website unfortunately had a minimal change between the 02.08 and 03.08. From then on your script wont work because he cant find the data on the exact same spot anymore.

You could try the following code to receive the data in a more stable way instead:

```
try:
    response = requests.get(url).content
    df_list = pd.read_html(response)
    #the searched data can be found in the 4 row and 4 column
    data.append(df_list[4][4])
```

this replaces your

```
try:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text)

    d = soup.select('table table tr:has(img[alt*="Fishing Gauge"]) td:has(p)')
    d = dict(zip(d[0].stripped_strings, d[1].stripped_strings))
    d.update({'date': start_date})
    data.append(d)
```

Comment: I just had to insert the additional "d.update({'date': start_date})" to fix the loop update and we were off to the races.